# What's the product name of DB2 for z/OS?

Tags: db2

According to [this document](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2z10.doc.java%2Fsrc%2Ftpc%2Fimjcc_c0053013.htm), DB2 for z/OS should return "DB2" as the `getDatabaseProductName` value. But in my Java application, it returns "DB2/MVS". Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

The simple reason is that the operating system you are using is [MVS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MVS). z/OS is just a name they slapped on it at later phase.